# Refresh rows in table, which are created from factory function (SAPUI5)

Tags: refresh, sapui5, factory

How can I "refresh" the data in rows inside a table? I know, that the table is refreshed, when the model is getting changed. But the problem is, that the rows are created by a factory method. The code for the rows looks like this:

```
formatter : function(text, id) {
                    if (text != null && id != null) {
                        if (this.getProperty("showId")) {
                            return text + " ( " + id + " )";
                        } else {
                            return text;
                        }
                    }

                    return "";
```

So, when I click on a button "hide ID" the property is getting changed and the table should be refreshed so that the content is built new. How can I do this? I checked the method `.refresh()` but this didn't work.

EDIT:
This is my column with the factory function:

```
columns : [ new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : "XYZ( ID )",
            filterProperty : "SHORT_TEXT",
            template : new sap.m.Label().bindProperty("text", {
                parts : [ {
                    path : "SHORT_TEXT",
                    type : new sap.ui.model.type.String()
                }, {
                    path : "ID",
                    type : new sap.ui.model.type.String()
                } ],
                formatter : function(text, id) {
                    if (text != null && id != null) {
                        if (this.getProperty("showId")) {
                            return text + " ( " + id + " )";
                        } else {
                            return text;
                        }
                    }

                    return "";

                }.bind(this)
            })
        })
```

This is the method, which changes the property:

```
onShowHideIdRequest : function(oControlEvent) {
    if (oControlEvent.getParameter("pressed")) {
        this.setProperty("showId", true);
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("oShowHideIdButton").setIcon("sap-icon://show");
    } else {
        this.setProperty("showId", false);
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("oShowHideIdButton").setIcon("sap-icon://hide");
    }

    sap.ui.getCore().byId("oTreeTable").rerender();
},
```

And the the property looks like this inside my component:

```
metadata : {
    properties : {
        showId : {
            type : "boolean",
            defaultValue : true
        }
    },
```

The "oTreeTable" ID refers to a `sap.ui.tableTreeTable`
I thought for a few days this all works fine, I don't know what's no wrong ...

Comment: if the odata model is changed, the formatter is getting triggered once again. What are you changing when you click the button? did you try updating the model manually? I assume you are currently doing changes on the table Content instead of the bound model?

Comment: I think .refresh should have done the job. Could you create a minimal viable jsbin example that shows the issue? I think that would help...

Comment: You could also use https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#refresh with bForce = true. An example would help though...

Comment: I added an edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the method you have written is formatter not the factory method. There is a difference between formatter and factory method. Formatter is used to return the value of a property of ui5 control based on some conditions or evaluation where as factory method is used to bind aggregations